# how to add many colors to single paragraph

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto

i try to make multi color in same line list but i get a wrong result

i need to make something like the below image :

### [image]

my current code :

```
paragraph = range.Paragraphs.Add();
paragraph.Range.Text = "Test";
paragraph.Range.Font.Color = Word.WdColor.wdColorSkyBlue;

paragraph = range.Paragraphs.Add();
paragraph.Range.Text = "Word";
paragraph.Range.Font.Color = Word.WdColor.wdColorRed;

paragraph = range.Paragraphs.Add();
paragraph.Range.Text = "Color";
paragraph.Range.Font.Color = Word.WdColor.wdColorBrown;
```

the result show 3 lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I need 50 rep to comment, I'll mark it as an answer.
From what I am reading, you should make a Sentence class and when you're done the sentence add it into your paragraph.